# How can I return a string with color from a function in c# Console Application?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am writing a function in c# (Console Application), and I want that the returned string will contain color, but just in one character.
Can I do it? How?

For example, the returned string is "Value: Queen, Shape: ♥", and I want that the heart will be red.

Comment: have a look at [this post](https://www.dotnetperls.com/console-color)

Comment: Is it always the last character that has to be colored, that way you don't have to specify what should be colored just what color and the string itself

Comment: EpicKip: yes, just the last character has to be colored. And Mong Zhu, this post explains just about colors of the output, and I need to paint the returned string itself

Comment: string don't contain information about color. You can write derived class ColorfulString with that information and your own Console.Write function that invokes normal Console.Write for normal strings, and takes into acount color information for ColorfulStrings. If your console app is a bigger project, this could be worth it

Comment: as @KrzysztofSkowronek already explained "string don't contain information about color". Just out of curiosity -> how will you use the color information? you don't intend to print the string to the console?

Comment: I print the string, but I thought that maybe it's possible that a string will contain color, so I will be able to print it just by "Console.WriteLine(str)", and without using Console.ForegroundColor

Comment: If you're using a terminal emulator or the new console in Windows 10 and have enabled the console's virtual terminal mode (or ANSICON or ConEmu), then strings can contain information about color by embedding VT sequences, e.g. `"Value: Queen, Shape: \x1b[31m♥\x1b[0m"`.

Answer (score 3):

You wont be able to use Console.WriteLine(), you will have to loop every character in the string and when you get to the character you want to be coloured use:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.Write(letter);
Console.ResetColor();
```

The full code could look like:

```
 string s = "Value: Queen, Shape: ♥";
 foreach (char c in s)
 {
     if(c=='♥') Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
     Console.Write(c);
     Console.ResetColor();
 }
```

Comment: Can't you just select the last character by index instead of `c==♥` because I suppose it would be a different icon at times

Comment: Yes if it's always the last character, you can so that

Comment: I know you can, I was merely suggesting it for your answer :)